# how to add data for all authenticated users in firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was looking for a way to add/upload data (global data) to firestore for all authenticated users of my app. It will be like a "admin app/panel" which can do the job, I guess? I am not really sure because I have not done this and new to firebase firestore.

My previous approach was :- Whenever a **new** user logins/signin, a local file having all the data (list type of data) will be uploaded to that specific authenticated user's document. If it is an **existed** user, I won't upload/add the **common** data again.

So as you can see, it is a very complicated/bad approach. This is the reason I'm looking for a better way like an **admin** method which can do the job of adding the common data to all users without me checking every-time.

(I even thought of doing it manually, like adding the data manually from firestore website, but there is no way of getting the user **uid** before authenticating him/her).

Comment: The data you want to add to every user is static or can change every time the user logs in?

Comment: @PeterKoltai it's static, just a field can change like, it's a list of objects, if user mark it as favourite item, I just set it `isFav` to `true`. That's it.

Comment: Have you considered using a Firebase trigger? For example if you have a users collection, you can execute a function whenever a new user document is inserted and add your extra initial data.

Comment: @PeterKoltai no, but I will take a look! Also, I was thinking of implementing an Admin role? That could help me to add data for all authenticated users from the admin panel? What do you think? How can I add the same data for each authenticated user?

Comment: If you want only to add a fix data to each user, you don't need admin role, because in Firestore triggers you will use Admin SDK, you won't need other authentication. If you need admin functions to be executed from frontend, you will definitely need an admin role, using custom claims.

Comment: @PeterKoltai okay thanks, will look into it!

Comment: @PeterKoltai Hi, I did a little bit of research and I couldn't find anything useful for `trigger function when new user registers in flutter firestore`. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

To execute some logic when a new user is created, setup `Firebase Functions` and create a function like below (assuming you have a collection called `users`):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// trigger on Firebase user creation
exports.onUserCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    return admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .set({
            data: 'whatever you need',
        }, { merge: true });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But I think this is for node/express right? Because there isn't any function like these in flutter for firebase firestore admin...

Comment: Yes, you must use Firebase Cloud Functions for triggers like this. They run within Firebase, not on your client.